# half of trackpad scrolls after upgrade to 19.10

Tags: touchpad

Half of the trackpad controls the mouse and the other half scrolls. This makes it really hard to navigate the GUI.

Comment: That's the way ThinkPad mousepads are designed to work. Mine works that way in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Debian 10, Windows 7, and Windows 10.

Comment: Trackpad works correctly with linux 5.0.0.32-generic and not on linux-5.3.0-19-generic.